# How to remove an option from mutli-picklist field in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, multi-select

I want to write an apex trigger action to remove a particular value from multi select picklist field based on some condition.How can I do this?

This is my trigger action:

```
public static void updateStopCom(map<Id, Account> accountOldMap, map<Id, Account> accountNewMap) {
   for (Id accountId : accountNewMap.keySet()) {
        Account newAccountValue = accountNewMap.get(accountId);
        Account prevAccountValue = accountOldMap.get(accountId);
        if ( (newAccountValue.Online__pc != prevAccountValue.Online__pc)){

             if(newAccountValue.Online__pc == true){
                newAccountValue.StopCom__c = ???; // how?
             }

        }
   }
}
```

StopCom__c is my multi select picklist field.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Is that, `newAccountValue.StopCom__c = '';` not working?

Comment: No, I want to remove particular value

Comment: Quick tip for other people looking at this question: `if(value == true)` can _always_ be simplified to `if(value)`. Likewise, `if(value == false)` simplifies to `if(!value)`. Just a way to save a bit of typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As multiselect picklist fields are stored as semi colon separated values, you will have to follow below steps to add/remove values to/from it.

- Split the values by semi colon and convert the string into `List`
- Add/Remove the element to/from the `list`
- Convert the `list` back to semi colon separated values using `String.Join` method

This is how your code should look like

```
string strPickListValue = newAccountValue.StopCom__c;
List<string> lstPicklistValues = strPickListValue.split(';');
string strValueToRemove ='abc';
if(lstPicklistValues.contains(strValueToRemove)){
    lstPicklistValues.remove(lstPicklistValues.indexOf(strValueToRemove));
}
newAccountValue.StopCom__c = String.join(lstPicklistValues,';');
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay !!

Comment: Glad to help you !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your multi-picklist value into List of string and iterate over it and do your execution(adding a value or removing it).

To split a multi-picklist value, In your case use like this:-

```
List<String> listofmultipicklisValues= String.valueOf(newAccountValue.StopCom__c).split(';');
```

To iterate over the string, A sample one would be like this:-

```
String Interests = '';
Boolean Start = true;
for(String Str : listofmultipicklisValues) {
    if(Start) {
       Interests = Str;
       Start = false;
    }else {               
       Interests = Interests + ';' + Str;
     }
 }
```

To remove a value directly in the List, Use like this:-

```
for(String Str : listofmultipicklisValues) {
   if(some condition){
      listofmultipicklisValues.remove(listofmultipicklisValues.get(str));
   }
}
```

At the end, add the list of string into single string again and update your muti-picklist field with that string.

Comment: Thank you sanket !!

Answer (score 0):

Vijay Ganji's answer is pretty good, though I would prefer to use a `Set<String>` here instead of a `List<String>`.

It won't make a difference in performance (or the list approach might be ever so slightly faster) given the number of values in a multipicklist field are usually very small, but it is slightly less typing.

This takes advantage of the fact that we have a constructor for `Set` that takes a list and that we have a constructor for `List` that takes a set.

```java
// Split the multipicklist value on semicolons
String strPickListValue = newAccountValue.StopCom__c;
Set<String> picklistValuesSet = new Set<String>(strPickListValue.split(';'));

// Remove the target value
string strValueToRemove = 'abc';
// If the multipicklist doesn't have our target value, the set will simply just
//   not be modified.
// Thus, we can remove the if() from Vijay's solution
// This is what saves us some typing (even though we have a little additional
//   typing elsewhere)
picklistValuesSet.remove(strValueToRemove);

// Join everything back together again
newAccountValue.StopCom__c = String.join(new List<String>(lstPicklistValues),';');
```

This is 291 characters vs Vijay's 340, though perhaps the more important thing is that we eliminated 2-3 lines of code (depending on how you count).

[As of Summer '23 (API v58.0), the `Set` collection type implements the `iterable` interface](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdX2vUAF/apex-code-implement-iterable-on-set), so we can just feed the set directly to `String.join()` instead of converting it back to a List.

```java
newAccountValue.StopCom__c = String.join(lstPicklistValues,';');
```

This makes the final character count 273